# match columns on different lines and sum

Tags: perl

I have a csv with about 160,000 lines, it looks like this:

```
chr1,160,161,3,0.333333333333333,+         
chr1,161,162,4,0.5,-      
chr1,309,310,14,0.0714285714285714,+     
chr1,311,312,2,0.5,-     
chr1,499,500,39,0.717948717948718,+     
chr2,500,501,8,0.375,-      
chr2,510,511,18,0.5,+         
chr2,511,512,6,0.333333333333333,-
```

I would like to pair lines where column 1 is the same, column 3 matches column 2 and where column 6 is a `'+'` while on the other line it is a `'-'`. If this is true I would like to sum column 4 and column 5.

My desired out put would be

```
chr1,160,161,7,0.833333333333333,+         
chr1,309,310,14,0.0714285714285714,+     
chr1,311,312,2,0.5,-     
chr1,499,500,39,0.717948717948718,+     
chr2,500,501,8,0.375,-      
chr2,510,511,24,0.833333333333333,-
```

the best solution I can think of is to duplicate the file and then match columns between the file and it's duplicate with perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl             
use strict;      
use warnings;          
open my $firstfile, '<', $ARGV[0] or die "$!";         
open my $secondfile, '<', $ARGV[1] or die "$!";            
my ($chr_a, $chr_b,$start,$end,$begin,$finish, $sum_a, $sum_b, $total_a, 
    $total_b,$sign_a,$sign_b);             

while (<$firstfile>) {
    my @col = split /,/;
    $chr_a  = $col[0];
    $start  = $col[1];
    $end    = $col[2];
    $sum_a  = $col[3];
    $total_a = $col[4];
    $sign_a = $col[5];

    seek($secondfile,0,0);
    while (<$secondfile>) {
       my @seccol = split /,/;
       $chr_b     = $seccol[0];
       $begin     = $seccol[1];
       $finish    = $seccol[2];
       $sum_b     = $seccol[3];
       $total_b   = $seccol[4];
       $sign_b    = $seccol[5];

       print join ("\t", $col[0], $col[1], $col[2], $col[3]+=$seccol[3], 
                         $col[4]+=$seccol[4], $col[5]), 
           "\n" if ($chr_a eq $chr_b and $end==$begin and $sign_a ne $sign_b);
    }
```

}

And that works fine, but ideally I'd like to be able to do this within the file itself without having to duplicate it, because I have many files and so I would like to run a script over all of them that is less time-consuming.
Thanks.

Comment: You are doing it within the file itself. You can run it over multiple files, just put a loop around it. Perhaps you could clarify what it is you are asking about?

Comment: instead of having to make a duplicate of the file to match column 3 and 2 (because they are on different lines) I was wondering if there is a simpler way.

Comment: Are the values of the first column always grouped together? And is the match between columns 3 and 2 always on consecutive lines, with the matching column being the 3rd in the first line with the 2nd in the one following?

Comment: You should realise that there is no need to duplicate a file to read the data with more than one file handle: you can just open it twice. But I'm afraid I can't guess what your problem is beyond that. My solution below sends the modified data to STDOUT, which you can redirect wherever you want, but I recommend that you don't overwrite the file in-place as any run may uncover a bug in your code that will mash that file beyond recovery.

Comment: Yes it is consecutive, your solution solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of a response to my comment, this program will do as you ask with the data you provide.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @last;

while (<DATA>) {
  s/\s+\z//;
  my @line = split /,/;

  if (@last
      and $last[0] eq $line[0]
      and $last[2] eq $line[1]
      and $last[5] eq '+' and $line[5] eq '-') {

    $last[3] += $line[3];
    $last[4] += $line[4];
    print join(',', @last), "\n";
    @last = ()
  }
  else {
    print join(',', @last), "\n" if @last;
    @last = @line;
  }
}

print join(',', @last), "\n" if @last;

__DATA__
chr1,160,161,3,0.333333333333333,+         
chr1,161,162,4,0.5,-      
chr1,309,310,14,0.0714285714285714,+     
chr1,311,312,2,0.5,-     
chr1,499,500,39,0.717948717948718,+     
chr2,500,501,8,0.375,-      
chr2,510,511,18,0.5,+         
chr2,511,512,6,0.333333333333333,-
```

**output**

```
chr1,160,161,7,0.833333333333333,+
chr1,309,310,14,0.0714285714285714,+
chr1,311,312,2,0.5,-
chr1,499,500,39,0.717948717948718,+
chr2,500,501,8,0.375,-
chr2,510,511,24,0.833333333333333,+
```